# jQuery select all in pagination not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

*My Question is*

> 1.If user click select all, I want to select all the rows. **Note:** Without using datatables, Because I am using laravel pagination.
>   2.While Clicking select all I am using sweetalert confirmation, In that User Clicked **Yes** I want to select all, If user Clicked **No** then nothing to worry
>   its already working for me.

[image]

```
 function checkallusers(){
      swal({
        title: 'Are you sure you want to make changes for entire Candidate?',
        text: "",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
        confirmButtonText: "OK",
        closeOnConfirm: false,
        showLoaderOnConfirm: true
      },
      function(isConfirm){
             if (isConfirm) {
                    //I want to select all the checkbox
                alert('yes');
                setTimeout(function(){swal("Success", "", "success"); },100);
             }else{
                //Nothing to worry else part working fine
                var checkboxCount = $(".bulkclass").length ;
                var checkedCount = $(".bulkclass").prop('checked', true).length ;
                 if(checkedCount < checkboxCount ){
                   $("#mainselect"). prop("checked",false);
                 }
                 if($("#mainselect"). prop("checked") == true){
                    $(".bulkclass").prop('checked', true);
                 }else{
                    $(".bulkclass").prop('checked', false);
                 }
             }
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute selector:

`$("input[type=checkbox]")`

Comment: Let me check it bro

Comment: how about `$("input[type='checkbox']")`

Comment: Try again becouse i made a typo.

Comment: @gizyk change `$("input[type=checkbox"])` for `$("input[type=checkbox]")`

Comment: I want to select all the select box, But its selected only in 1 page

Comment: You can't select checkboxes on the pages that weren't loaded. You need to find other solution. Can you show me what you want to do exactly after selecting all checkboxes ?